# How to configure Jaybird with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, firebird, jaybird

I'm using jaybird 2.2.3 with hibernate 3.5 and when I use the wizard to hibernate mapping files and pojos database the following error appears
"java.lang.NullPointerException"

I use the same mapping with mysql and it works correctly, so I believe it is something in jaybird

```
My hibernate.cfg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD       3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:firebirdsql://XXXXXX:XXXX/X:\XXXX\XXXX\XXX\XXX\XX\XXX.FDB</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sysdba</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXX</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Edit:

```
INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: configuring from file: hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Configured SessionFactory: null
INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository]: Override file: C:\Documents and  Settings\micro-40\workspace\testefirebird\src\java\hibernate.reveng.xml
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil]: Found pre-existing database  connection.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil]: Database Connection is pre-established. Returning the conneciton.
INFO [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory]: Initializing connection provider: org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.CustomJDBCConnectionProvider
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.CustomJDBCConnectionProvider]: Loaded JDBC driver 
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.CustomJDBCConnectionProvider]: Got connection.. returning
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor]: access  to hibernate fails.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2005)
    at     org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:40)
    at  org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor.checkConfig(Hibernat    eCodeGenWizardDescriptor.java:282)
[catch] at    org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor.isValid(HibernateCod    eGenWizardDescriptor.java:177)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateStateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:872)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:820)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.updateState(TemplateWizard.java:754)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewFileWizard.updateState(NewFileWizard.java:124)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor._updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:798)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$200(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.stateChanged(WizardDescriptor.java:2094)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$Change.stateChanged(WeakListenerImpl.java:329)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.run(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:275)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEvent(Mutex.java:1343)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:457)
    at     org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.fireStateChanged(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:261)
    at     org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.setIterator(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:120)
    at     org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.setIterator(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.    java:79)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.setTemplateImpl(TemplateWizard.java:209)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$1.run(TemplateWizard.java:231)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$1.run(TemplateWizard.java:228)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:273)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.setTemplate(TemplateWizard.java:228)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplateChooserPanel.storeSettings(TemplateChooserPanel.java    :168)
    at     org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplateChooserPanel.storeSettings(TemplateChooserPanel.java     :71)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.storeSettingsAndNotify(WizardDescriptor.java:1379)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1700(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2117)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1502)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1900(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2141)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at    java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1076)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1126)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1098)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:128)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:273)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1083)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at   org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.showDialog(DialogDisplayerI    mpl.java:260)
    at   org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.run(DialogDisplayerImpl.jav    a:186)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

can someone help me?

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I could not find this NullPointerException stracktrace.

this is the image of the error

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/in28.png/

could help me find the stracktrace this NullPointerException?

thank you

Comment: I'd suggest to look in the Netbeans logging (eg `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\<version>\var\log` on Windows)

Comment: I found messages.log and posted and edited the question

Comment: See also https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=146785 and https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212636 However I have seen it before in a more recent version of Netbeans; it is a bug in Hibernate tools as far as I know, and not directly related to Jaybird. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500429/nullpointerexception-in-netbeans-hibernate-mapping-files-and-pojos-wizard-from-f

Comment: I thought I had seen/found a workaround for this, but I have to dig for it.

Comment: should be bug netbeans, I'm using NetBeans 7.3 and Java 1.7.0-17

Comment: Looking at the code of Jaybird and the netbeans code involved it might be a classloading issue. I will investigate. I created ticket http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the code of Netbeans and adding extra logging to Jaybird, the problem is that Netbeans loads the driver with a custom classloader that doesn't return resources in `META-INF/services` (specifically for Jaybird 2.2.x: `META-INF/services/org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSFactoryPlugin`).

This breaks the driver as these services definitions are used to load the available `GDSFactoryPlugin` definitions (eg one for the Type 4 default implementation, Type 4 Open Office implementation, the Type 2 embedded client and Type 2 native client).

I will add some kind of fallback mechanism or move this plugin definition to a separate location and also investigate why Netbeans does this, because it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

## Solution

Use [Jaybird](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/) 2.2.4 or higher.

## Workaround

**NOTE**: Do not use this workaround, it was superseded by the release of Jaybird 2.2.4

<s>As a workaround I have released a snapshot build of Jaybird 2.2.4, you can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-jca-jdbc-driver/2.2.4-SNAPSHOT/ (make sure it has today (21st of September) as the build date, it is possible that some of the sourceforge mirrors still distribute the previous snapshot).</s>

A full list of changes in 2.2.4 can be found in the Jaybird tracker: [Version 2.2.4](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC/fixforversion/10531).

Comment: then, with current versions of the jaybird and netbeans can not hibernate reverse engineer?

Comment: @TiagoRoquedeCarvalho No unfortunately it doesn't. I will release a 2.2.4-SNAPSHOT version with a workaround this weekend.

Comment: @TiagoRoquedeCarvalho I have uploaded the snapshot, see the edit of my answer for details.